# CSS Counter Only for Child List Items

Tags: css

Is it possible to display only decimal numbers and not the whole numbers at the top level of an ordered list outline?  For example:

```
<ol>
<li>Item 
    <ol>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>Item
    <ol>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
```

CSS

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;                
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: section;                                                  
  content: counters(section,".") " ";
}
```

That would display a list like:

1. Item
    
      1.1 Item
      1.2 Item
      1.3 Item

What I would like to achieve is:

Item
 
   1.1 Item
   1.2 Item
   1.3 Item

Here is a fiddle I've been trying things out with: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Py7k8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;                
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:before {
  counter-increment: section;                                                
  content: "";
}
li ol li:before {                                             
  content: counters(section,".") " ";
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/8X3ef/1/)